# How to display JSON task results stored via django-celery-results framework in django template?

Tags: python, json, django, django-celery

In my project, i am using [django-celery-results framework](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results) to access celery task results. The framework stores task results as JSON format. One of the results is figured out below;

```
"{\"runs\": [{\"run_number\": 1, \"run_date\": \"2018-08-17 10:13:53.488079\", \"cycle_number\": 0, \"global_best\": {\"number_of_fitness_cases\": null, \"functions\": [{\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}], \"n_features\": 1, \"constants\": [{\"value\": 0.1}, {\"value\": 0.2}, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"value\": 0.4}, {\"value\": 0.5}, {\"value\": 0.6}, {\"value\": 0.7}, {\"value\": 0.8}, {\"value\": 0.9}, {\"value\": -0.1}, {\"value\": -0.2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.5}, {\"value\": -0.6}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"value\": -0.8}, {\"value\": -0.9}], \"terminals\": [{\"value\": 0.1}, {\"value\": 0.2}, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"value\": 0.4}, {\"value\": 0.5}, {\"value\": 0.6}, {\"value\": 0.7}, {\"value\": 0.8}, {\"value\": 0.9}, {\"value\": -0.1}, {\"value\": -0.2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.5}, {\"value\": -0.6}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"value\": -0.8}, {\"value\": -0.9}, 0], \"full_set\": [{\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": 0.1}, {\"value\": 0.2}, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"value\": 0.4}, {\"value\": 0.5}, {\"value\": 0.6}, {\"value\": 0.7}, {\"value\": 0.8}, {\"value\": 0.9}, {\"value\": -0.1}, {\"value\": -0.2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.5}, {\"value\": -0.6}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"value\": -0.8}, {\"value\": -0.9}, 0], \"random_state\": \"<mtrand.RandomState object at 0x7efc35c67240>\", \"max_depth\": 5, \"method\": \"full\", \"program\": [{\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, 0, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.2}, {\"value\": -0.6}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.4}, 0, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"value\": -0.2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.1}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": 0.9}, {\"value\": 0.8}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": 0.9}, {\"value\": 0.8}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": -0.1}, {\"value\": 0.9}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": 0.4}, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": 0.4}, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, 0, {\"value\": -0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.4}, {\"value\": -0.1}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'multiply'>\", \"name\": \"mul\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.3}, 0, {\"function\": {}, \"name\": \"div\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"value\": -0.2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'subtract'>\", \"name\": \"sub\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, 0, {\"value\": 0.3}, {\"function\": \"<ufunc 'add'>\", \"name\": \"add\", \"arity\": 2}, {\"value\": -0.7}, {\"value\": 0.9}], \"raw_fitness_\": 0.0017450904199366553, \"hits\": 0, \"trial\": 2, \"probability\": 1.0, \"metric\": {\"function\": {}, \"title\": \"Mean Square Error\", \"greater_is_better\": false, \"sign\": -1}, \"depth_\": 10}}], \"average_cost\": 0.0017450904199366553}"
```

The `result` field of the [TaskResult](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/master/django_celery_results/models.py) model is a TextField therefore its type is string. Code snippet that i used in my views.py figured out below;

```
run_list = request.user.run_set.all().order_by('-start_time')
context = {'run_list': run_list}
return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', context)
```

When i try to access elements of the result of a run in run_list, i failed. Because it is not a JSON object in template. I tried the code snippet is figured out below;

```
<table>
{% for run in run_list %}
    <tr><td> {{run.task.result.average_cost}} </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

It is displaying nothing... After that i tried to convert result field to JSON but i failed again. Tried code below;

```
run_list = request.user.run_set.all().order_by('-start_time')
for run_item in run_list:
    run_item.task.result = json.loads(json.loads(run_item.task.result))
```

So, what is the solution? How can i access `average_cost` element of the result field in template?

Comment: Stating "I failed again" without explaining HOW you failed is totally useless (cf http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will add the details of failures. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
run_item.task.result = json.loads(json.dumps(run_item.task.result))
```

just remove the `json.dumps(...)` call:

```
run_item.task.result =  json.loads(run_item.task.result)
```

nb : `json.dumps(obj)` is to serialize a Python object to a json string.

Edit :

> It's not working. Type of result is string again

That must have something to do with how `run_item` (whatever it is - you didn't post your model code) handles it's `result` attribute. I can't tell exactly what the proper solution would be without knowing your code, but the best I can think of with right now would be to make your `Run` model responsible for the `task.result` json parsing, ie:

```
import json

class Run(models.Model):
    # your code here

    def results(self):
        return json.loads(self.task.result)
```

Then remove the whole processing from your view and in your template just use `run.result.average_cost`.

Comment: It's not working. Type of `result` is string again. In template, nothing displayed.

Comment: @CeylanB. cf my edited answer. I can assure you that passing your example result string to `json.loads()` does work (that's the fisrt thing I tested before answering).

Comment: you mean run.result**s**.average_cost instead of run.result.average_cost, right?

Comment: I tried updated solution and it's not working too. The same. Type of result is string again. For the sake of easiness, i add a template tag to get type of an object. When i apply your solution, the type of result seems `<class 'str'>` again.

Comment: i've solved the problem. I have added an extra `json.loads` to `return json.loads(self.task.result)`. And the type of `result` changed to `dict`. Could you please update your answer accordingly? This line `return json.loads(self.task.result)` should be `return json.loads(json.loads(self.task.result))`.

Comment: I will not update my answer because having to apply `json.loads()` twice to get a correct result really means **you have another problem uphill** where the `result` is doubly json-encoded, and **the proper solution is to avoid this double encoding at the source**, not to doubly decode it here.

Comment: I found the problem, actually i am not sure it is problem or not. I am running a celery shared task. The task function is returning an object that is not serializable. I forced to serialize returning object using json.dumps function. Therefore, result encoded two times.